# Клавиатура внутри layout'а

Tags: android, android-fragment, клавиатура

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, как можно вставить свою клавиатуру внутрь layout'а/fragment'а? Или может есть библиотека какая?

[image: пример]

Единственное что сейчас придумал дак это создать xml, там с помощью таблицы нарисовать клаву и обьеденить это с классом, в котором будет навешан KeyListener